# symfony2 does not use http 304 with AppCache and render_esi

Tags: symfony, esi

we have a symfony 2.3.35 application in which we make use of the setLastModified header to enable client side caching.
For performance improvements we enabled AppCache as reverse proxy but also had to make use of render_esi for a client specific controller via twig:

```
{{ render_esi(controller('Bundle:Controller:method')) }}
```

After that all pages are served with a http status 200 instead of a 304 like done before render_esi. When disabling render_esi the 304 do return.

My question: is this intended? Does the AppCache kernel need the requests to fullfill the fragment requests for the esi controller? Isn't this a performance gap then (makes more usage of CPU etc.)?

Using hinclude seems to do the trick but it looks a little bit outdated to me...

Am I doing it the wrong way?

Thanks in advance!